# Angular injecting $service results in Unknown provider: $serviceProvider

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Why when I run this in the karma runner:

```
describe('Service tests', function () {


    var DataServiceMock
    var httpBackend;


    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function( $httpBackend, $service, DataService,  $injector){
```

results in this error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $serviceProvider <- $service
>     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24serviceProvider%20%3C-%20%24service
>         at /home/site/angular/angular.js:78:12

Edit 2_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

I'm trying to mock the DataService for the dataHandlerService

```
describe('Service', function () {


    var DataServiceMock
    var httpBackend;

    var testUrl = "test/";

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(){
    module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('DataService', DataServiceMock)
        })
    }));

    it('should have', inject(function(DataService) {
        expect('DataService').not.toBe(null);
    }));
```

and this error:

> Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!
>         at workFn (/home/me/root/angular/angular-mocks.js:1985:15)

Comment: Because there is not a $service to inject. What is that $service you want to be injected?

Comment: @idursun I have an Angular DataService that I want to mock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no $service. If you want to mock your service then you should do it by using $provide:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  DataServiceMock= {}
  DataServiceMock.doSomething = function() {}
  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('DataService', DataServiceMock)
  })
})
```

Comment: Creating a mock is putting there something that mimics the actual implementation. But in your edit, I see that you are trying to get the actual service from the injector. Since you called the injector before the module provide routine, you are getting the error. You should be creating your mocks like in my answer...

Comment: please see my second edit, sorry if its taking me a while to get this.

Comment: Please make sure `module(function($provide))` is called before any inject call. Can you also add the code that is before the module call?

Comment: actually I just want to instantiate a custom $http (the only think I need to change) into the DataService. I think now I don't need to create a mock of DataService

Comment: In your code it goes like beforeEach -> inject -> module. That is exactly what the error message indicates injector is already created so you cannot add a module. It should be as in my answer, you have to call inject _after_ the module call.

Comment: If you encapsulate your `DataService` logic in a service, then you don't even have to deal with `$httpBackend` while testing. You just need to get used to this module injections in tests thingie.