# injector already created. can not register a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a new bee to Angular JS and was trying to make something out of it in a proper TDD way, but while testing i am getting this error:

> Injector already created, can not register a module!

**This is the service i am talking about.**

```
bookCatalogApp.service('authorService', ["$resource", "$q", function($resource, $q){

    var Author =$resource('/book-catalog/author/all',{},{
        getAll : { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });

    var authorService = {};

    authorService.assignAuthors = function(data){
        authorService.allAuthors = data;
    };

    authorService.getAll = function(){
        if (authorService.allAuthors)
            return {then: function(callback){callback(authorService.allAuthors)}}

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Author.getAll(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
            authorService.assignAuthors(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return authorService;
}]);
```

**This is the test for the above service**

```
describe("Author Book Service",function(){
    var authorService;
    beforeEach(module("bookCatalogApp"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        authorService = $injector.get('authorService');
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe("#getAll", function() {
        it('should get all the authors for the first time', function() {
            var authors = [{id:1 , name:'Prayas'}, {id:2 , name:'Prateek'}];

            httpBackend.when('GET', '/book-catalog/author/all').respond(200, authors);

            var promise = authorService.getAll();

            httpBackend.flush();
            promise.then(function(data){
                expect(data.length).toBe(2)
            });
        });

        it('should get all the authors as they have already cached', function() {
            authorService.allAuthors = [{id:1 , name:'Prayas'}, {id:2 , name:'Prateek'}];

            var promise = authorService.getAll();

            promise.then(function(data){
                expect(data.length).toBe(2)
            });
        });

    });
})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular injecting $service results in Unknown provider: $serviceProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186368/angular-injecting-service-results-in-unknown-provider-serviceprovider)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you are mixing calls to `module('someApp')` and `inject($someDependency)` you will get this error.

All your calls to `module('someApp')` must occur before your calls to  `inject($someDependency)`.

Answer (score 7):

You're using the *inject* function wrong. As the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) states, the *inject* function already instantiates a new instance of $injector. My guess is that by passing $injector as a argument to the inject function you are asking it to instantiate the $injector service twice.

Just use *inject* to pass in the service you want to check. Underneath the covers, *inject* will use the $injector service it instantiates to grab services.

You can fix this problem by changing the second *beforeEach* statement to:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_authorService_) {
    authorService = _authorService_;
}));
```

One other thing to note. The argument authorService passed to the *inject* function has been wrapped with '_' so it's name does not hide the variable created within the *describe* function. Thats also documented in the inject [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is the cause, but your beforeEach should be like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  inject(function($injector) {
    authorService = $injector.get('authorService');
  }
});
```

Comment: Passing $injector into the inject function is redundant and is whats causing the problem in this scenario.

Comment: This is perfectly legitimate way to inject a service.

What might be happening is you cannot use the $provide.value paradigm after you have used mocks.inject when setting up your tests. In fact, you cannot use $provide.value after ANY mocks.inject statements, even if your mocks.inject statement involves an unrelated module.