# Reusing angular mocks in Jasmine tests using $provide

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

I wish to reuse my mocks instead of having to set them up in every unit test that has them as dependency. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to inject them properly.

Here's my attempt at unit test setup, which of course fails because ConfigServiceMockProvider doesn't exist.

```
describe('LoginService tests', function () {

  var LoginService;

  beforeEach(module('mocks'));

  beforeEach(module('services.loginService', function ($provide, _ConfigServiceMock_) {
    $provide.value("ConfigService", _ConfigServiceMock_);

    /* instead of having to type e.g. everywhere ConfigService is used
    *  $provide.value("ConfigService", { 'foobar': function(){} });
    */
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (_LoginService_) {
    LoginService = _LoginService_;
  });
}
```

ConfigServiceMock

```
angular.module('mocks').service('ConfigServiceMock', function() {
  this.init = function(){};
  this.getValue = function(){};
}
```

I realize I probably could have ConfigServiceMock.js make a global window object, and thereby not needing to load it like this. But I feel there should be a better way.

Comment: Where is the definition of `mocks.ConfigServiceMock`

Comment: Added it to question

Comment: The module name is `mock` not `mocks.ConfigServiceMock`. Can you change to `beforeEach(module('mocks'));` and try.

Comment: You are right, I misspelled it when writing to SO. 

Let me try to specify, the problem isn't compilation, its that I'm looking for a pattern to inject pre-defined mocks into my unit tests.

Comment: You mean to say `_ConfigServiceMock_` service injection is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
describe('Using externally defined mock', function() {
  var ConfigServiceMock;

  beforeEach(module('mocks'));

  beforeEach(module('services.configService', function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('ConfigService', function() {return ConfigServiceMock;});
  }));

  beforeEach(module('services.loginService'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_ConfigServiceMock_) {
    ConfigServiceMock = _ConfigServiceMock_;
  }));

  // Do not combine this call with the one above
  beforeEach(inject(function (_LoginService_) {
    LoginService = _LoginService_;
  }));

  it('should have been given the mock', function() {
    expect(ConfigServiceMock).toBeDefined('The mock should have been defined');
    expect(LoginService.injectedService).toBeDefined('Something should have been injected');
    expect(LoginService.injectedService).toBe(ConfigServiceMock, 'The thing injected should be the mock');
  });
});
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29114169/12480), you have to put all of your calls to `module` before all of your calls to `inject`.

This introduces a bit of a catch-22 because you have to have the reference to your ConfigServiceMock (via `inject`) into the spec before you can set it on the LoginService (done in the `module` call)

The work-around is to set an angular factory function as the ConfigService dependency.  This will cause angular to lazy load the service, and by that time you will have received your reference to the ConfigServiceMock.

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believe there is no documentation on this as reusability of mocks should be important in any large application.