# AngularJS / Karma testing: beforeEach not executed

Tags: angularjs, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm working on some TDD for AngularJS (another story altogether) and ran into a situation where my beforeEach calls are apparently not being executed.  I reduced it down to the following example.

This works as evidenced by the fact that the console.log messages in beforeEach and it both appear:

```
describe('userApp', function(){ 
  beforeEach( function(){ 
    console.log("in beforeEach...");
  }); 

  it('should be able to log something', function(){ 
    console.log("in it...");
  }); 
});
```

This doesn't work, as evidenced by the fact that the console.log message in the beforeEach is NOT displayed and the it fails when attempting to $log.info and throws the error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`

```
describe('userApp', function(){ 
  var $log;
  beforeEach(module('userApp', function($provide) {
    console.log("in beforeEach...");
    // Output messages
    $provide.value('$log', console);
  })); 
  it('should be able to log something', function(){ 
    console.log("in it...");
    $log.info("Using $log for logging...");
  }); 
});
```

I'm using Angular 1.3.15, karma 0.12.31, jasmine 2.3.4. Probably something obvious I'm overlooking...

**EDIT**: Michael Radionov's explanation is very helpful; however, I don't understand why this modified code still throws the same error.

```
describe('userApp', function(){ 
  console.log("starting TEST3");   <=== this prints
  var $log;
  beforeEach(function() {
    console.log("TEST3: in beforeEach...");   <=== this prints
    module('userApp', function($provide, _$log_) {
      $log = _$log_;
      console.log("TEST3: in beforeEach/module...");   <=== never executed
      // Output messages
      $provide.value('$log', console);
      $log.info("TEST3: calling $log in beforeEach...");
    })
  }); 
  it('should be able to log something', function(){ 
    console.log("TEST3: in it...");
    $log.info("TEST3: Using $log for logging...");  <=== $log undefined err
  }); 
});
```

Furthermore, it seems the code in "module('userApp'..." is never executed...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your log message `console.log("in beforeEach...");` is not being displayed is because it is not actually inside `beforeEach`, it is inside an anonymous function passed to a `module(..)` as an argument which is considered to be a module by angular-mocks. This module will be executed only when injection happens and at the same time you'll receive a log message `in beforeEach...`, but there is no any injection in your test, so it never happens. `beforeEach` fires anyway, you just didn't put `console.log` in the right place; it will work:

```
beforeEach(function () {

  console.log("in beforeEach...");

  module('userApp', function($provide) {
    // Output messages
    $provide.value('$log', console);
  });

});
```

Also it seems that you forgot to inject mocked `$log` into you test suite, your `$log` variable never gets any value, so it stays undefined as the error states.

```
describe('userApp', function(){ 

  var $log;

  beforeEach(function () {
    console.log("in beforeEach...");

    module('userApp', function($provide) {
      // Output messages
      $provide.value('$log', console);
    });

    // getting an instance of mocked service to use in a test suite
    inject(function (_$log_) {
      $log = _$log_;
    });

  }); 

  it('should be able to log something', function(){ 
    console.log("in it...");
    $log.info("Using $log for logging...");
  }); 

});
```

See the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EirNEthh4CXdBSDAeqOE?p=preview

Docs:

- [angular.mock.inject](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)
- [angular.mock.module](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)

Comment: Thanks, Michael... that starts to help. I'm going to update the post with another  sample that seems as if it should work. It's sounding as if -- even though the beforeEach() all do get executed, the module() code inside them doesn't necessarily get executed at the same time?

Comment: In your update you try to inject `_$log_` using `module()`, but it's not gonna work. `module()` is only for registering modules which will be executed when you call `inject()`. Injection is the work on injector. If you call `inject()` right here in before each, it may be considered "*at the same time*". In my sample I've moved `inject` to the same `beforeEach` to make it a bit more clear that

Comment: Thanks, Michael; You've done a fine job of explaining this. However, this is where Angular just starts getting crazy, IMO.  If I put the 'inject' first, followed by the 'module' statement, then I get "Injector already created, can not register a module!". There's already a discussion about that on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900067/injector-already-created-can-not-register-a-module with many different approaches... note the argument over the answer by @gilamarn. Seems like testing in Angular is very persnickety.

Comment: I wonder why do you need to `inject` before `module`. Try to look at it this way: `module` registers your modules/services/factories/controllers like in real app; `inject` - kinda starts this app. If you call `inject` first (means that your app has already been started), you can't register new modules after that and call `inject` again (start app again). The same applies to test workflow. This example is very very broad, but might help to understand.